# QGIS reshape tool and enable tracing (snap) tool

Tags: qgis, features, digitizing, trace

I know how to increase or change the size of a polygon with the reshape tool, but can you also use Enable Tracing tool  with it, as you can with drawing a new feature?

Comment: Well, have you tried to do so?

Comment: yes - but not sure if I'm doing it wrong, or it just doesn't work with reshape tool